# My wordpress site is trying to load corehivejs.com and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, wordpress

https://xn--clausius-wrmepumpen-pwb.de/ when loading is trying to load the file: corehivejs.com/corehive-1.0.min.js:1

I've searched every file in my plugins folder and my theme folder. There is no mention of "corehive" in any of them.

The inspector feature of Firefox throws this error:
Failed to load resource: corehivejs.com/corehive-1.0.min.js:1
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I've searched all of the WordPress files. I also exported the database and searched that as well. There is no mention of corehive anywhere. Neither is there the shortened URL version: goo.gl/S81S2N

There are many plugins installed. I've tried disabling all plugins. Nothing changed.

SOLVED: It was the theme. I couldn't find the link (the goo.gl one or the real one) anywhere in the files or database. But when I switched the theme, it went away.

Comment: i guess it is a expired analitical js file.check your plugin list .may be there is a plugin related to analytics.try disabling them.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha there are no analytics plugins. I'll add a list of the installed plugins to the question.

Comment: disable all the plugins and check whether script is still loading or not.ones it's confirm you can enable one by one and detect the related plugin.otherwise it's coming from theme

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha thanks for the tip, I've done that. But even with all plugins disabled, it's still the same. I would like to try and change the theme. But I'm not sure if it won't screw up the widgets and menus and stuff.

Comment: i checked the site.search didn't work for you because it's loaded from short url `goo.gl/S81S2N` search for this url in your folders

Comment: Strange, the search didn't find any goo.gl URLs in either the plugins nor the themes folder. This is getting pretty weird. If you have the time, could you tell me how you found this shortenend goo.gl URL?

Comment: check the browser network tab   https://imgur.com/Fs0jWR7

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. I will now download all the wordpress files and search them. Who knows where that thing is hiding. Probably better check the database too.

Comment: Checked all the files AND the database. Nothing. I am speechless.

Comment: try to switch theme to some other one, after open website in the incognito mode. it's some analytics, which may be part of theme

Comment: Thanks @SamvelAleqsanyan - one question: will the theme settings be lost if I switch the theme and then go back? (I didn't make or install the theme, so I don't want to screw it up)

Comment: no, settings should stay as they were before

Comment: Thank you guys. It was the theme. I will tell the site owner to contact the theme creator and let them sort this out. Thanks very much for your help!